# Robots meta tag with "noimageindex"

Tags: web-crawlers, images, meta-robots

I have some doubt regarding `noimageindex` value in meta robots tag. If I add this tag on my page say `http://www.example.com/somepage/someaction.php` and on that page the images are served from another page say `http://www.exampleimg.com`.

Then will the tag has meaning. I mean to say will the images will be ignored by bots? Or `exampleimg` is not affected by that tag. And all images will be indexed?

Note: We want to stop indexing of the images on that particular page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for the page you need to ignore indexing of images (by adding the following meta tags):

```
<meta name="robots" content="noimageindex">
```

This tag will prevent indexing images from your site or external site on that page.

Answer (score 2):

**Blocking images from Google**

Use any of the two tags,

```
<meta name="robots" content="noimageindex">
```

Or,

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noimageindex">
```

Note that the images on the page may still be included in the image index if they are linked to by other pages.

See the below links.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79892?hl=en

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag

Comment: Please explain a little bit the content of the link. It helps the question owner to understand quickly your answer. Moreover, without explaining a little bit more, if the link goes to 404 in the future, your answer will be useless.

Comment: @Zistoloen I edited my answer.

Comment: I think the linked document is incomplete as it doesn't explicitly state that it prevents the indexing of images on that page, it simply states that the page won't be recognised as the referring page. However, the [Google docs on the Robots META tag](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag) explicitly states, "Do not index images on this page."